# How do I add a title tag to these images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with images inside and I'm trying to use jQuery UI to make individual tooltips for each image. Currently I'm wanting to use JavaScript to display the images but am stuck on implementing title tags for each image. If anyone could tell or show me how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Link to the website: [www.thetotempole.ca/javascriptproject2.html](http://www.thetotempole.ca/javascriptproject2.html)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arrays</title>

<style>
#tbl img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
          transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

#tbl td:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
}
td {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <center><table id="tbl" border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Product Images</th>
         </tr>
  </table>
<script>
var products = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    description: "It might be fruit, or it might be an iPhone",
    imageUrl: "images/apple.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Dell",
    description: "Buy this one online at dell.com",
    imageUrl: "images/dell.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "IBM",
    description: "If you want a mainframe they still have some",
    imageUrl: "images/ibm.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Toshiba",
    description: "Get a discount through SAIT (maybe)",
    imageUrl: "images/toshiba.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Atari",
    description: "Try a classic gaming machine",
    imageUrl: "images/atari.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Commodore",
    description: "64k should be enough for anyone",
    imageUrl: "images/commodore.jpg"
  }
];

var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
products.forEach(function(product) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.name));
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.description));
  row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl));

  table.appendChild(row);
});

function createCell(text) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.innerText = text;
  return cell;
}

function createImageCell(url) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", url);

  var cell = document.createElement("td");  
  cell.appendChild(image);
  return cell;
}

</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using tooltips from the jQuery UI?  http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/  You can add effects and colors to your tooltips that are hard coded into your img.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, unfortunately I cannot seem to figure out how to implement individual titles for each image which is required for the JQuery UIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add title in each json array

```
{ 
  name: "Apple", 
   description: "It might be fruit, or it might be an iPhone",
  imageUrl: "images/apple.jpg",
  title: "title1"
}, { ........}
```

Edit this  line

```
row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl));
```

To

```
row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl, product.title));
```

Edit this function

```
 function createImageCell(url)
```

To

```
function createImageCell(url,title){
...
```

Add title attribute to image:

```
image.setAttribute("title",title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

Pass the title in createImageCell function and add the title attribute to that image

Change the function as

```
products.forEach(function(product) {
  ....
  row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl, product.name));

});


function createImageCell(url, product_name) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", url);
  image.setAttribute("title", product_name);
```